# Inline assembly issue with LLVM 4.0

Tags: assembly, clang, inline-assembly, neon, llvm-4.0

On Xcode 4.4, I have some problems compilling inline assembly on the last LLVM compiler (4.0).

In my inline assembly code, each call to "fldmias" like :

```
asm volatile(    
"fldmias  %2, {s4-s19}    \n\t"
...
)
```

give me this error :

**Inline assembly issue** :
Instruction 'fldmia' can not set flags, but 's' suffix specified

The same code works well with LLVM GCC 4.2. Maybe there is some difference between configuration for each compiler but I don't find anything.

Thanks.

Comment: Try `fldmsia` maybe?  It's possible the mnemonic doesn't match.  My manual here puts the addressing mode in the middle like you have it, but I can see why an implementer would choose to only accept them at the end.

Comment: Actually I think read something about clang using UAL - did you try the UAL equivalent?  The book I have here says that would be `VLDMIA.32`, I think.

Comment: Invalid instruction with the s on the middle, the s is here for setting the precision (here single precision), and maybe the compiler identify this letter as the conditional suffix...

Comment: it's definitely identifying the `s` as the "set flags" suffix, like in `adds` or `subs`, for example.  I can see how that would confuse it, since the addressing mode goes in the middle of the instruction.  Did the UAL one also not work?  I'll try to make a test file here and see what I come up with.

Comment: Yes it works with the UAL equivalent, so VLDMIA.32 in place of FLDMIAS. Thank you for your help, Carl.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As discovered in the comments above, the answer here is to use the UAL equivalent instruction, which in this case is:

```
VLDMIA.32 %2, {s4-s19}
```